# Customise bottom Navigation using xamarin forms c#

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, cross-platform, bottomnavigationview

I need to design bottom navigation bar like I attached image using xamarin.forms common code for both android and IOS. Can anybody refer any link or library tool to do this?

[image]

Comment: Check the [Sharpnado tabs library](https://github.com/roubachof/Sharpnado.Tabs) or [this](https://www.andrewhoefling.com/Blog/Post/xamarin-forms-shell-customizing-the-tabbar-android) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/170862/xamarin-bottom-custom-tab-bar.html) articles.

Comment: Thanks for Response.Can you suggest any other example.Sharpnado tabs library is fine but it doesn't have full example.So can  you refer Example code.

Comment: You can check: https://github.com/roubachof/Xamarin-Forms-Practices .

Answer (score 0):

You should check the xamarin community toolkit, this is certainly possible to create with the tabview.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/views/tabview